# Getting a 404 error with Jersey with Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I've spent a quite a few hours working on this and still haven't been able to come across a solution that will work. I have moved all the jar files to the WEB-INF folder set the build paths.

I'm using Jersey 2, with Tomcat 8 on Eclipse. http://localhost:8080/ is working fine, and displays the Tomcat page. However, I visit http://localhost:8080/JerseyLivin/rest/hello I get a 404 error page -

```
type Status report

message /JerseyLivin/rest/hello

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Here is the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JerseyLivin</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>JerseyLivin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The java class file, Hello.java:

```
package jerseyLivin;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

And the tomcat log file:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:06 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:09 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:09 -0700] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:09 -0700] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:09 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:12 -0700] "GET /JerseyLivin/rest/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 1038
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:11:37:12 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

Is there something I am not seeing that is producing the 404 message?

Comment: can you please verify your package name in the web xml ? its upper case vs lower case package name

Comment: @ShivV I've restarted this project from scratch in hopes that it would fix my problem. I am still having the same issue and I've created a JerseyLivin package for the Hello.java file. The web xml and Hello.java is the same as above, except Hello.java now has `package JerseyLivin;` instead.

Also, when I choose to run Hello.java, it tries to open `http://localhost:8080/JerseyLivin/WEB-INF/web.xml`, which has the same error message. Is this link supposed to be working? Thanks for the help!

Comment: now we'll have to see your jars because the same set up worked just fine for me

Comment: you can add this logging filter to see some logs which will help           <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>

Comment: @ShivV, here are my jar files: [Gyazo Link](https://i.gyazo.com/5959c6581e798798636ddff13ff1bf41.png) I'll try the logging and see if I find anything. I just add this to the web.xml file, correct?

Comment: Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/raw/9Ti0as4y

Comment: not sure if you need both the jersey-container-servlet and jersey-container-servlet-core dependency. I only have jersey-container-servlet-core. that's the only diffference I see here.

Comment: try with the below init param`<init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>your package  </param-value>
         </init-param>`                                   and did you registered your resource class ?  looke at  here [jersey user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#environmenmt.appmodel)